# Excel Activex Listbox to open and close on selection of same cell without needing to click out onto another cell first

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, activex

This code shows ListBox1 when cell A2 is clicked, hides it when A2 is clicked a second time or ListBox1 is no longer selected. The selections are output to A2.

The problem is that after A2 is clicked once to open and once to close, you must click another cell before clicking on A2 again to create the perceived toggle effect of the ListBox.

I have tried repeating `Application.EnableEvents = False` `[A3].Select` `Application.EnableEvents = True` just before `End If` however when trying to select any other cell on the sheet, only A3 is selected.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.ListBox1
        If Target(1).Address = "$A$2" And .Visible = False Then
            .Visible = True
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            [A3].Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        Else
            .Visible = False
            For I = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(I) Then txt = txt & ", " & .List(I)
            Next
            [A2] = Mid(txt, 2)  'remove first comma and output to A2 cell
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Question Updated to include the answer provided, while incorporating part of the code from above to output the ListBox selections to cell A2. The new problem is that the selections already made, continue to multiply in cell A2 everytime the ListBox is closed, rather than only adding new selections.

```
Option Explicit

Dim SelectCell As Boolean
Dim i As Long
Dim txt As String

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.ListBox1
        If Target(1).Address = "$A$2" And .Visible = False Then
            .Visible = True
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            [A3].Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            SelectCell = True
        Else
            .Visible = False
            
            For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
                If .Selected(i) Then txt = txt & ", " & .List(i)
            Next
            [A2] = Mid(txt, 2)  'remove first comma and output to A2 cell
            
            
            If SelectCell = True Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                [A3].Select
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                SelectCell = False
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: putting `Application.EnableEvents = False [A3].Select Application.EnableEvents = True` just before `End If` works for me

Comment: Yes this works however when you click any other cell in the sheet it keeps selecting cell A3. I will clarify question. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Yes this works however when you click any other cell in the sheet it keeps selecting cell A3. I will clarify question. Thanks – aye cee 1 min ago

Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Dim SelectCell As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    With ActiveSheet.ListBox1
        If Target(1).Address = "$A$2" And .Visible = False Then
            .Visible = True
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            [A3].Select
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            SelectCell = True
        Else
            .Visible = False
            If SelectCell = True Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                [A3].Select
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                SelectCell = False
            End If
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

> The Listbox should open and close endless times by clicking A2 or close by clicking outside, while also allowing selection of other cells on the sheet. Yes I included all code. On your end can you repeatedly click A2 to open close without selecting any other cell? – aye cee 2 mins ago

It does exactly that. See this

[image]

**Alternate solution**

Use `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` with `Worksheet_SelectionChange`. See this. Now the `ListBox1` will show everytime you double click on `A2` and hide when any other cell is selected.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target(1).Address = "$A$2" And ListBox1.Visible = False Then
        ListBox1.Visible = True
        Cancel = True
    Else
        ListBox1.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ListBox1.Visible = True Then ListBox1.Visible = False
End Sub
```

Comment: This also only allows click to open and click to close, once. After that you must click another cell before clicking A2 to open/close one more time.

Comment: I am sorry but I do not undertsand what you mean? Can you refresh the page and try the code? Perhaps i was editing the post?

Comment: What the above code does is when you click on A2, it shows the listbox and selects A3. When you click a cell (other than A3), it closes the listbox and select A3. Now if you select any other cell, It will not jump to A3 like it was doing earlier.

Comment: I tried the edited code. I click A2 once, Listbox opens. Click A2 a second time, Listbox closes. Click A2 a third time, nothing happens. If I click a random cell, I can then select A2 to open the Listbox again.

Comment: `I click A2 once, Listbox opens. Click A2 a second time, Listbox closes. Click A2 a third time, nothing happens.` Well it works for me. Did you copy the complete code including `Dim SelectCell As Boolean`?

Comment: The Listbox should open and close endless times by clicking A2 or close by clicking outside, while also allowing selection of other cells on the sheet. Yes I included all code. On your end can you repeatedly click A2 to open close without selecting any other cell?

Comment: Wait I will embed this screenshot in the above answer

Comment: I have seen it. Strange. I will try recreating in a blank file.

Comment: Updated my answer with the screenshot

Comment: BTW have you condidered using `Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick` instead of `Worksheet_SelectionChange`? That ways you will not need the `[A3].Select` part anymore

Comment: No I hadnt, Im not too experienced with the different methods. If the code is simpler then even better. Do I just remove `[A3].Select`?

Comment: I updated the post above. you may have to refresh it to see it.

Comment: The alternate solution seems to require clicking another cell in order to repeat the open/close. The original solution works well for me in a blank file so there must be a conflict of some sort in my original file.

Comment: I leave the choice with you :)

Comment: Thank you for all your help. Just struggling trying to add back in the code that outputs selections to cell A2 and getting a "variable not defined" error for "i" (using the first code you posted).

Comment: I then get the same error for "txt". Im not sure if I have inserted it in the correct position. I have inserted `For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1` `If .Selected(i) Then txt = txt & ", " & .List(i)` ` Next` `[A2] = Mid(txt, 2)` after `If SelectCell = True Then`

Comment: You are getting this error becuase of `Option Explicit` which forces you to declare your variables and objects. Like you did for others, add `Dim txt As String` on top

Comment: When I open/close the ListBox it adds the selections already selected to A2 over and over.

Comment: It wasn't doing this prior, its just the way it fits in with the new code. However no issue I can ask a new question. Thank you.

Comment: Can you update your question with the new code that you are using?

Comment: Move `Dim txt As String` after `Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)` and before `With ActiveSheet.ListBox1`

Answer (score 1):

I see that you already have a solution. However, for what it's worth, here is another approach. I think it allows you more flexibility to control what the ListBox shows when it is displayed.

```
Option Explicit

Private Const Trigger       As String = "A2"

Private Sub ListBox1_LostFocus()
    ' 238

    Dim Txt     As String
    Dim i       As Integer
    
    With ListBox1
        For i = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(i) Then
                If Len(Txt) Then Txt = Txt & ","
                Txt = Txt & .List(i)
            End If
        Next i
        Range(Trigger).Value = Txt
    End With
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    ' 238
    
    With ListBox1
        If Target.Address(0, 0) = Trigger Then
            .Visible = True
            .ListFillRange = "P2:P9"
        Else
            .Visible = False
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

In the above setup the ListBox is displayed when the user clicks on A2. He can then make a selection and transfer it to A2 by clicking anywhere outside the ListBox. However, if he clicks on A2 he can see both his selection and its transscription to A2, and go back to the ListBox to change the selection.

Comment: Have tried your code also. Only issues are the inability to toggle the visibility of the ListBox with A2 and also that ListBox items dont stay selected so each time a selection is made the previous selections are reset.

Comment: Thank you for trying my code. I apologize for not having read the many comments. Therefor I only know what your questions says. I thought you wanted to click A2, make a selection in the ListBox and proceed. I took a guess and expanded some effort on removing the selection. It's done by resetting the ListFillRange. Due to the structure of my code - responding to 2 events instead of one - adjustments are fairly simple.

Comment: Thank you and no need to apologize. I appreciate the input, and may use it if my needs change or I become more proficient at adapting the code.